# Multiindex Re-indexing - custom sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

How do you reindex a multiindex? I have 2 indexes, where the first one requires a manual sort, and the 2nd index is by descending order.

In the below, index1 needs to be custom sorted by: Cat-B, Cat-A, Cat-C; index2 by descending order.

```
Index1 Index2
Cat-A  Apple
       Orange
       Banana
Cat-B  Mango
       Lychee
Cat-C  Kiwi
       Nectarine
```

to:

```
Index1 Index2
Cat-B  Mango
       Lychee
Cat-A  Orange
       Banana
       Apple
Cat-C  Nectarine
       Kiwi
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need `pd.CategoricalIndex` however since this orders in one direction we will manually need to invert the order.

```
cati = pd.CategoricalIndex(
    df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), ["Cat-C", "Cat-A", "Cat-B"], ordered=True
)
#note 'Cat-C' is first but will be last when we sort the index.

df.index = df.index.set_levels(cati,level=0)

print(df.sort_index(0,level=[0,1],ascending=False))
                   A
Index1 Index2       
Cat-B   Mango      0
        Lychee     0
Cat-A   Orange     0
        Banana     0
        Apple      0
Cat-C   Nectarine  0
        Kiwi       0
```